# Tensorflow "wheel not supported", Having Issues with Tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow, neural-network, pip, anaconda

So, I've looked at several different sources, but I cannot find anything that has worked. At first, I got "no module called tensorflow", so I tried installing again (on windows 64-bit), and tried both anaconda and also pip, using the following wheel: https://storage.googleapis.com/tensorflow/windows/cpu/tensorflow-1.0.1-cp35-cp35m-win_amd64.whl, and yes I used "--ignore-installed". Both said something along the lines of "this wheel is not supported on the platform". I hate to bring up a topic which has already been brought up, but I've looked through stack overflow and tried out all the proposed solutions, and none solved the issue.  I'd really appreciate any help, I've been stuck on this for a few days.  Here are some specifications that might give some insight.  Python is 3.6 64-bit, anaconda 4.3 64-bit, my system is obviously 64-bit. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Tensorflow 1.0 [does not support 3.6](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/6999) (on Windows, at least)

Answer (score 0):

The wheel you used is for Python 3.5 64-bit, it will not work with Python 3.6. Either download the Python 3.6 version or use it with Python 3.5.

The wheel's filename holds this information, the `cp35` part means Python 3.5 (CPython, actually, but that's the ordinary Python you use), `win` means Windows and `amd64` means 64 bit.

Comment: Oh god, I feel so dumb... But thanks, I appreciate it.